# doclicense incompatibility with pdfmanagement

Tags: latex3, metadata, hyperxmp, doclicense

Package `doclicense` is now incompatible with the new `pdfmanagement` when the latter is, as I understand it, invoked automatically by the `\DocumentMetadata` command. And the cause seems to be that `doclicense` automatically loads `hyperxmp`, whereas loading `hyperxmp` is disabled by pdfmangement.

Is there a workaround?

```
\DocumentMetadata{%
  testphase=phase-II,
  uncompress,
  lang=en-US,
  pdfstandard=a-2u}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[type={CC},modifier={by-nc-nd},version={4.0},lang={english}]{doclicense}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdflicenseurl={http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/},
  pdfproducer=pdfTeX-1.40.24, % still needed?
}

\begin{document}
  Hello
\end{document}
```

From the log:

```
Package pdfmanagement Warning: The loading of package hyperxmp is disabled.
(pdfmanagement)                It is not compatible with the PDF management.


(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/doclicense/doclicense-english.ldf))
./cr-problem.tex:9: Undefined control sequence.
\__hook file/doclicense.sty/after ... \hypersetup 
                                                  {pdfcopyright={\doclicense...
l.9
```

Comment: hm, yes. Load hyperref before doclicense.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: No, loading hyperref before doclicense gives the same error (with pdfmanagement invoked by \DocumentMetatdata).

Comment: no it doesn't. I tried. Show your log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You are, of course, right: reversing the load order fixes this error. (Not sure what I did first time I tried that.) I note that this is a relatively new error with pdfmanagement: I had happily used pdfmanagement with load order (1) doclicense, (2) hyperref for some time.

Comment: the next update should repair this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Next update of which - doclicense or hyperref?

Comment: Pdfmanagement-testphase, should be now in texlive.